# Is there a way to describe a relation between two parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Suppose there's a function `f` that takes two parameters `a: A` and `b: B`, with `A` having a property `prop` of type `B`:

```
interface A {
  ...
  prop: B
  ...
}

interface B {
  ...
}

function f(a: A, b: B): R {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way in TypeScript to enforce through a type system, that the second parameter points to the same object of type `B` as the property `prop` in the first parameter?

i.e. `a.prop === b`

Comment: Maybe defining function like `f(a: A): R{ .... }` and using `a.prop` inside the function instead of passing it as a parameter? (I assume you can change function definition. If not, please ignore this)

Comment: I don't want to know the reason why you are sending it in that way but that what you want is technically not possible because at compile time you can only check types and not object values. Values you can check only in runtime -  so that means you will need an "if" in your function that will check the equality of your A prop and B.

Comment: @Ismar makes total sense, thanks! If you convert this to a proper answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to know the reason why you are sending it in that way but that what you want is technically not possible because at compile time you can only check types and not object values. Values you can check only in runtime - so that means you will need an "if" in your function that will check the equality of your A prop and B.

Comment: Fan fact: StackOverflow literally shows me a notification "You can't accept an answer that is less than 1 minute old". And then is showed me "You can accept it in 18 seconds". I have no ide why they do it :D Once again, thank you!